# any tutorials/blogs regarding uploading more than one db images

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have exhausting goggle looking for a way to upload more than one db images.
I had a look at

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/125/ASP.NET-MVC-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files or http://mattias-jakobsson.net/post/2009/11/19/Handling-image-uploads-with-AspNet-Mvc.aspx or http://www.johnpscott.co.uk/devnotes/picpick/default.aspx or http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/ and so on. I no luck.

Does anyone has a tutorial or recommend a book that demostrate how to upload more than one db images. I am using vs 2010, asp.net mvc3 in C# with SQL Server 2008R2. All I am trying to do is to have couple db images for each product.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link you provided is a good start for what you need.

- Store all images for a product change....

It shows how to upload multiple files. From this you could modify the table where the images are inserted to add a key for the record relation back to your product.

- Retrieve all images for a product change...

To pull them back from the database you would call the code in the same article (GetFile), modifying the select statement to include your product key INSTEAD of the ID of the individual image.

- Display all images for a product change...

This is where it changes quite a bit.  The author of the first article still returns one file as a FileContentResult.  Obviously, this won't work for your situation.

[Have a look at this article.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/imaageinmvc06172009102628AM/imaageinmvc.aspx)  It uses an XML file to load up multiple images BUT you would replace this code with the code in GetFiles to create the Image List.  It shows how to create a controller, model and view for this.  You could create a partial view to have the images on the same page as the product view.

[This sample shows how to get an image list out of the DB into a view.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1491579.aspx) (To help with modifying GetFiles to better work for this...)